# Denver time zone shows EDT, -0400, should be MDT, -0600

Tags: ntp

Output from %timedatectl status is "Time zone: America/Denver (EDT, -0400)"

Something is corrupt since Denver is in fact MDT, -0600.

Is there a file I can remove and replace?

Edit: As Jaromanda has pointed out, the file to replace is "Navajo", which is pointed at by Denver.  Deleted Navajo, copied over Edmonton and renamed it to Navajo.  Now all is well when I select Denver as my timezone and reboot.

I'll attempt to mark this question as answered if this is possible.  Or someone reading this with more experience, kindly feel free to do so.

Comment: Tried %sudo ntpd -q -g with no apparent effect.

Comment: Using sudo raspi-config to change to Los_Angeles, I see the correct PDT, -0700.  Seems only my time zone of Denver is corrupt.

Comment: what is the output of `ls -l /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Denver`

Comment: also, output of `zdump Navajo America/Denver US/Mountain` (all 3 times output here should be the same)

Comment: ls -l /usr/.../Denver returns lrwxrwxrwx root root ...  as expected.  Also, for what it is worth, if I select Edmonton, Canada as my location I get the correct -0600 offset and my Pi clock shows the correct MDT.  I am thinking to replace the /usr/.../Denver with one from another working Pi.

Comment: `as expected` - so it is a link (`lrwxrwxrwx`) to `../Navajo`? which is what you expected? don't replace `/usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Denver` if it is a symbolic link ... what it links to (`/usr/share/zoneinfo/Navajo` ?) is what you need to deal with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replaced the suspected corrupt Navajo timezone file with a working one - Edmonton.  Renamed it to Navajo, selected Denver in the Pi configuration dialog, rebooted and all is well.

Comment: Edmonton and Navajo are NOT the same - Edmonton has 3 fewer transition times - though, this will only cause issues if dealing with times before 1975 - which may not be an issue for you

Comment: I've uploaded my Navajo zone file ... so you can get it using `wget https://pastebin.com/raw/VYXZJdDu -O - | xxd -p -r > Navajo`

Comment: I have retrieved your Navajo file - thank you.

For the record, my Pi is dedicated to a clock radio and historical times are of no concern; only the present and the future.  

It was likely that my attempt to program the current timezone from within the clock code was responsible for the corruption - but I have no way of proving that.

Again, thanks for your input and file.